# Will File.lastModified value always increase?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, last-modified

I'm trying to monitor a file for changes in Java running on either Windows or Linux.

Currently I am looking into polling the last-modified property of the file instead of hooking into OS file events in an attempt to avoid dealing with smoothing over the API differences and handling asynchronous events.

I'm storing the result of `new File("path").lastModified()` once I've processed the file and comparing new `lastModified` results every `x` seconds.

Can I rely on the fact that, assuming no foul play and someone manually modifying the timestamp, lastModified will always increase? The Java docs say that it is an offset from a GMT epoch, so presumably it won't go backwards even with timezone adjustments?

Comment: Normally that's good, even in time shifting zones.

Comment: I don't see how you can assume 'no foul play' or nobody 'manually modifiying the timestamp'. You also can't assume the CPU clock is never set backwards: it happens at least once a year at the end of DST. If the file is modified twice within an hour across that even it can appear up to 59 mins 59 seconds older than previously.

Comment: @EJP: Daylight savings is just a timezone issue, and the OP is right that this alone wouldn't cause the actual value of a Date (or in this case, a timestamp) to go backwards (just to be formatted differently).

Comment: @EJP I'm assuming no foul play because deleting the file (something I can't easily prevent) would have the same affect as moving the last modified timespamp backwards - it doesn't get processed. I'm looking for scenarios where it might legitimately get moved back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the timestamp of a file to anything

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?touch

If time is corrected using something like NTP, it can go backwards.

These situations are rare, and it might not be something you need to worry about.

Comment: Hmm, presumably if the clock is skipped backwards (from something like NTP correcting drift) Java's File.lastModified isn't going to be able to correct for that?

Answer (score 5):

Well, sometimes, `lastModified` does not increase. It is all about time resolution and the resolution is different in each file system:

- all `FAT`s (FAT32, FAT16, FAT12) have a `2 second` time resolution,
- for `NTFS` it is `100 ns` (yep, *nanoseconds*)
- for most **nixes* its `1 second`.

So, if your files will change rapidly, `lastModified` will not change, and your *monitor* may lose some changes.

This is also very tricky, because if you have the same file on different filesystems (like FAT32 and NTFS) their `lastModified` time **will** differ due to different time resolution. Now because ot that, you may be reacting to *fake file changes* that did not happen - it's just the `FAT32` returning a time that is 1 second different than the `NTFS` time. This is also the case with web servers - if you don't know the server file system, then you don't know what the time resolution of the value in a HTTP Header is.

The workaround is to assume, that the file did not change if the difference between stored value, and FS value is less than 3-4 seconds. That's what `WebStart` does when checking for new versions of JAR files on the server.

Comment: Presumably WebStart can afford to read, hash and compare the files because it's doing so relatively infrequently? That might be too costly.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "if you obtain the last modified time from other source". I'm reading the last modified time I'm comparing against using File.lastModified() and storing that.

Comment: 1. Webstart downloads files from a simple HTTP. So there is no way to calculate a hash on the server side. 2. If you have a file on NTFS filesystem, and a copy of that file on FAT32 filesystem, the `lastModified` time may differ due to different time resolution -i'll update the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: So your point is if I'm taking last-modified from NTFS and comparing it to last-modified on FAT32 they may differ because of time resolution? I'm always reading on the same filesystem so I don't think that will be an issue?